# Run Concept Annotation Tool (CAT) using Docker

Tags: docker, command-line

I am trying to run CAT using docker. "If using docker the appropriate models will be automatically downloaded, you only need to run:"

```
    docker build --network=host -t cat -f Dockerfile.MedMen .
```

As it says in the following website: https://libraries.io/pypi/medcat

I have tried to run exactly the same command in Command Prompt.

The error I get is the following one:

```
    unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: GetFileAttributesEx U:\Dockerfile.MedMen: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I don't understand what file the system cannot find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clone the [respective Git repository](https://github.com/w-is-h/cat). Then run the command from there.

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem, consider [accepting this answer](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).